Disable "Go to Folder" in Finder views in apps
I have macOS Monterey. I have created a user, "user1", that has read and write access to a path /usr/local/.work/. Now, I have provided this user only VNC access and disabled Finder for it. Now I have opened Chrome browser for "user1". Now the problem is when the user presses Cmd+O, it can get to the above-mentioned directory using Go to Folder feature (Cmd+Shift+G)
How can I disable "user1" to view any files in the mentioned folder, even though it has both read and write access?

without changing the permissions of /usr/local/.work or files under it
without disabling the shortcut (Cmd+Shift+G)
without ProhibitGoToFolder = 1 in the Finder plist (as it is not working)


chmod -r /usr/local/.work will prevent anybody from listing its content. Does this match your needs?

This sentence, "I have provided this user only the UI access and disabled finder for it." It seems to make no sense. "UI" is user interface. On the Mac that is called the Finder. It is unclear what you are trying to say here.

Sorry @SteveChambers for conusion, by UI access, I mean VNC access.

VNC is a screen sharing tool, it does not access directories like a file browser.

I think you're missing what you want the user to be able to do. Why are you VNC'ing into a machine just to use a browser? Why does the user account need access to files that the human user should not be able to access? Obviously you can "solve" the access issue by disabling VNC, but surely that is not what you want.

I don't have a solution for you, but trying to restrict access without actually changing the access controls is going to be difficult
